# Writing a class validator/maintaining proper OOP

Tags: php, json, oop, validation

I have a class called Component, which is the base class for many other types of Components (e.g., Text, Image ...) and looks like so:

```
function __construct($data) {...}

abstract public function build();
...other methods, getters and setters
```

The way in which these components are used is as follows:

1. User uploads settings to create a specific component type
2. Component settings are cleaned and stored in a DB
3. User, at a later time, specifies which of their components to use and sends the appropriate data

Currently, I get the settings for each component through a JSON object the end-user sends me... so what I'd like to do, is build a validator/cleaner to assist me in part #2 above.

All of the validation code is already in each component via their getters and setters, so ideally what I'd like to do, is try to create a component with the settings provided by the user and see if there were any errors.

The only problem with this, is each component requires data to be initialized -- as many other internal functions require the data to be set.

I've thought of a couple ways to deal with this (see below), but I'm not a fan of any of them. So I'd like your ideas on how to tackle this.

- Separate the settings into their own class so both the components and validator can use them without requiring any "data"
- Use dummy data for the components

Comment: Seems like you `Component` class should not be inherited, and instead it should be a Factory/Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you are trying to do, here's what I would probably do.

Create a static method on your object(s) that will validate all of the component settings in one call. This static method could instantiate a dummy object (somewhat like you were saying), and in turn use the validation that's already built in to your getters and setters. This object could then be thrown away and the static method could return some sort of assertion if the validation passed. You could alternatively have the static method return some sort array of errors if simply returning a boolean isn't sufficient.

Comment: Man... why did I not think of that. I'll try it out and see how it works, thanks!